# Views and forms for users updating key/value collections in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and have a set of name/answer pairs for each level in which a user can update:

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :answer, :level_id, :user_id
end
```

It's such a pain to create the many views:

```
<li<%if @error_fields.include?('example_name') or @error_fields.include?('example_other_name')%> class="error_section"<%end%>>
  <%= label_tag 'answer[example_name]', 'Example question:' %> <%= text_field_tag 'answer[example_name]', @user_answers['example_name'], placeholder: 'Enter answer', class: @error_fields.include?('example_name') ? 'error_field' : '' %>
  <%= label_tag 'answer[example_other_name]', 'Other example question:' %> <%= text_field_tag 'answer[example_other_name]', @user_answers['example_other_name'], placeholder: 'Enter other answer', class: @error_fields.include?('example_other_name') ? 'error_field' : '' %>
</li>
```

`@user_answers` is clearly a hash holding the user's answers from the last update. There's so much repetition above. What's the best way to handle this in Rails? I'd love to use something like `form_for`, but I don't think I'm able to because this isn't a single model object, this is a collection of `UserAnswer` ActiveRecord instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In helpers add:

```
def field_for(what, errors = {})
  what = what.to_s
  text_field_tag("answer[#{what}]",
    @user_answers[what], placeholder: l(what),
    class: @error_fields.include?(what) ? 'error_field' : '')
end
```

Then add proper keys to your `en.yml` in `config/locales`. The only thing you need to write is:

```
<%= label_tag 'answer[example_name]', 'Example question:' %> <%= field_for :example_name, @error_fields %>
```

Comment: I'd probably want both the label and field in the helper, but this looks like the right approach

Comment: Then just add label to helper. I haven't done it because it can make some problems.

Comment: With translate/display proper message, but if you think it will be easy and simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Rails 3.2 [ActiveRecord Store](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#active-record)?

It seem like a much easier way to store key/value and allows you to just say `@user_answer.example_name` instead of `answer[example_name]`.  Then you could just have an example_name field in your form.

```
class UserAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :answers, accessors: [:example_name, :example_other_way]
end

answer = UserAnswer.new(example_name: "Example Name")
answer.example_name returns "Example Name"
```

Comment: I was unaware of ActiveRecord Store, looks interesting. Basically a text field. Though I can't have the answers in a serialized field in the database.